# trying to build a TF2 model with multiple output, but get InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 8

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I build a model from pretrained resnet50

this is my code

```
resnet50 = keras.applications.resnet.ResNet50(include_top=False,weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3))

#resnet50.summary()
resnet50.trainable = False

model = keras.Sequential([
    resnet50,
    keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Dense(8,activation='softmax',name='output1')
    ])

model.summary()

IMGSZ = 224
input_image = keras.layers.Input((IMGSZ,IMGSZ,3),dtype=tf.float32)
x = model.layers[0](model.input)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
output = keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax',name='output2')(x)
model2 = keras.models.Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=[model.output,output])
model2.summary()

base_learning_rate = 0.001
model2.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_learning_rate),
             loss={'output1':'categorical_crossentropy','output2':'categorical_crossentropy'},
             metrics=['accuracy'])

hsitory = model2.fit(aug_db,epochs=1000,steps_per_epoch=200)
```

the aug_db is a iterator will return the
image (32,244,244,3) ,category (32,8) and another category (32,2)

the task is trying to recognize the image category and the position category
but I got the error

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 8
     [[node categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Squeeze (defined at <ipython-input-61-98d8531d42d0>:27) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_398664]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I have tried to pass a random tensor (1,224,224,3) to the model2.

And tried to get an image from aug_db then pass it to the model2, then calculate the loss between the model2 output and aug_db category correctly.

but when I use model.fit() it will get the error above.

I think it is because of the loss in model.compile().

I have checked the output and the aug_db, still don't know what's going on.

Comment: Provide more details about what aug_db is and what is it's shape. It would be best if you can produce a Minimal Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you!! I have edited my question, hope it will be more clear.